# Alternative to TControl.Perform

Tags: windows, delphi, message-queue, vcl

the `TControl.Perform` code is:

```
var
  Message: TMessage;
begin
  Message.Msg := Msg;
  Message.WParam := WParam;
  Message.LParam := LParam;
  Message.Result := 0;
  if Self <> nil then WindowProc(Message);
  Result := Message.Result;
```

The program execution awaits return, am i right?

There is an alternative, for posting a message in a TFORM queue, inside another thread, in the same Application, without waiting return?

### EDIT

This approach could mitigate the problem?

```
interface

const  
  WM_DOSTUFF = WM_APP + $001;

TMyForm = class(TForm)
{stuff}
public
{Other stuff}
  procedure DoMyStuff(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_DOSTUFF;   
{More stuff}
end;  

var
  MyHandle: HWND;

implementation

constructor TMyForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  MyHandle := AllocateHWnd(DoMyStuff);
end; 

destructor TMyForm.Destroy;
begin
  DeallocateHWnd(MyHandle);
  inherited;
end;
```

And use normally inside a thread:

```
  PostMessage(MyHandle, WM_DOSTUFF, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a message to the queue of the thread associated with another window, you need to use the [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) Windows API function.

```
PostMessage(WindowHandle, Msg, WParam, LParam);
```

Now, if you are doing this on a different thread from the GUI thread, then you cannot use `Form.Handle` to obtain the window handle. That's because doing so introduces a race with the GUI thread. And if the handle needs to be re-created, it will be created with affinity to your thread rather than the GUI thread. Remember the rules: only interact with VCL objects from the GUI thread.

So you typically do not use `PostMessage` with the handle of a VCL form because you cannot easily guarantee that the message will be delivered to the correct window. Even if you synchronize access to the window handle, the window can be re-created and your message will not arrive.

The simplest way to deliver messages asynchronously is to call [`TThread.Queue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue). This does not need a window handle to operate and so avoids all the issues with VCL object affinity to the GUI thread. The procedure that you send when you call `Queue` executes on the GUI thread and so is safe to perform all VCL operations.

If you are on an older Delphi that pre-dates `TThread.Queue` then it is more complicated. You should in that case use `PostMessage`. But you'll have to direct the message to a window not associated with a form. Direct it to a window created with [`AllocateHWnd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd). Remember that you must call `AllocateHWnd` on the GUI thread. Windows created this way are immune from re-creation and are safe targets for `PostMessage`. The window procedure for that window can then forward the message on to your form. And that is safe because the window procedure executes in the thread associated with its window. In this case that is the GUI thread.

As an aside, if you are calling `TControl.Perform` away from the GUI thread, then that is also wrong. Expect intermittent and hard to diagnose failures.

Comment: what are the complications you mentioned about prior versions than TThread.Queue, about AllocateHWnd?

Comment: What kind of failure may be expected, using perform TControl.Perform?

Comment: The complication is that you cannot use `TThread.Queue` because it does not exist in older versions of Delphi. That's what I mean when I said "an older Delphi that pre-dates `TThread.Queue`".

Comment: All sorts of failures are expected. You are breaking the rules. You are only allowed to call use VCL controls on the GUI thread. If you call `Perform` then you'll run the WindowProc on the wrong thread and have no synchronisation. Anything could happen.

Comment: May i call AllocateHWnd(Self.WindowProc), in TForm.Constructor?

Comment: I don' think it will work to have two distinct windows backed by a single window procedure. I think you'll need a dedicated window procedure for the `AllocateHWnd` window.

Comment: `inherited AllocateHWnd(DoMyStuff);` makes no sense. You need to create a field to store the window handle. And allocate that with the window returned by `AllocateHWnd(DoMyStuff)` But then you'll be good.

Comment: sory, i forgot the ";" and "CRLF"

Comment: OK, but you are posting the message to the wrong handle. Needs to go to `MyHandle`.

Comment: I'm too dumb, sorry, check it now please.

Comment: You don't need the `if` I think. If the form exists, the handle exists. You do need to make sure that the form always exists.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i'll fix and accept the answer, i'm new in Windows programming and new in Delphi too, and this is a very big world, thanks a lot