# Ensure all TThread.Queue methods complete before thread self-destructs

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have discovered that if a method queued with `TThread.Queue` calls a method that invokes `TApplication.WndProc` (e.g. `ShowMessage`) then subsequent queued methods are allowed to run before the original method has completed. Worse still, they don't seem to be invoked in FIFO order.

[Edit: Actually they do start in FIFO order. With `ShowMessage` it looks like the later one ran first because there is a call to `CheckSynchronize` before the dialog appears. This unqueues the next method and runs it, not returning until the latter method has completed. Only then does the dialog appear.]

I'm trying to ensure that all methods queued from the worker thread to run in the VCL thread run in strict FIFO order, and that they all complete before the worker thread is destroyed.

My other constraint is that I am trying to maintain strict separation of the GUI from the business logic. The thread in this case is part of the business logic layer so I can't use `PostMessage` from an `OnTerminate` handler to arrange for the thread to be destroyed (as recommended by a number of contributors elsewhere). So I'm setting `FreeOnTerminate := True` in a final queued method just before TThread.Execute exits. (Hence the need for them to execute in strict FIFO order.)

This is how my TThread.Execute method ends:

```
finally
  // Queue a final method to execute in the main thread that will set an event
  // allowing this thread to exit. This ensures that this thread can't exit
  // until all of the queued procedures have run.
  Queue(
    procedure
    begin
      if Assigned(fOnComplete) then
      begin
        fOnComplete(Self);
        // Handler sets fWorker.FreeOnTerminate := True and fWorker := nil
      end;
      SetEvent(fCanExit);
    end);
  WaitForSingleObject(fCanExit, INFINITE);
end;
```

but as I said this doesn't work because this queued method executes before some of the earlier queued methods.

Can anyone suggest a simple and clean way to make this work, or a simple and clean alternative?

[The only idea I've come up with so far that maintains separation of concerns and modularity is to give my `TThread` subclass a `WndProc` of its own. Then I can use `PostMessage` directly to this WndProc instead of the main form's. But I'm hoping for something a bit more light-weight.]

---

Thanks for the answers and comments so far. I now understand that my code above with a queued `SetEvent` and `WaitForSingleObject` is functionally equivalent to calling `Synchronize` at the end instead of `Queue` because `Queue` and `Synchronize` share the same queue. I tried `Synchronize` first and it failed for the same reason as the code above fails - the earlier queued methods invoke message handling so the final `Synchronize` method runs before the earlier queued methods have completed.

So I'm still stuck with the original problem, which now boils down to: Can I cleanly ensure that all of the queued methods have completed before the worker thread is freed, and can I cleanly free the worker thread without using `PostMessage`, which requires a window handle to post to (that my business layer doesn't have access to).

I've also updated the title better to reflect the original problem, although I'd be happy for an alternative solution that doesn't use `TThread.Queue` if appropriate. If someone can think up a better title then please edit it.

---

Another update: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16090524/127670) by David Heffernan suggests using `PostMessage` with a special `AllocateHWnd` in the general case if `TThread.Queue` isn't available or suitable. Significantly, it's never safe to use `PostMessage` to the main form because the window can be spontaneously recreated changing its handle, which would cause all subsequent messages to the old handle to be lost. This makes a strong argument for me adopting this particular solution, since there's no additional overhead to creating a hidden window in my case since *any* application using `PostMessage` should do this - i.e. my separation of concerns argument is irrelevant.

Comment: Seems that Queue isn't the right choice here. You might consider using Synchronize instead.

Comment: @UweRaabe I should have said that the queued methods need to execute asynchronously to the worker thread. The worker thread can wait only once it has finished all its work and is ready to exit.

Comment: IMHO the requirement that `all of the queued methods have completed before the worker thread is freed` indicates a (too) strong coupling between this thread and the queued methods, which are executed in the context of a different thread

Comment: @mjn This arises because there is a requirement that the main thread can terminate the worker thread at any time. But since the main thread can't use the usual PostMessage technique to free the worker thread from its OnTerminate handler then we have to use FreeOnTerminate := True, but this cannot be set until all queued methods have completed because all methods still in the queue when the thread is destroyed get destroyed with the thread. But I'm open to other ways of achieving my objectives. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @mjm Actually I *could* use PostMessage to free the thread if the thread had its own WndProc; arguably this is the only reliable way to do it anyway. But if I use Windows messaging for that then I might as well go the whole hog and use Windows messaging instead of TThread.Queue everywhere. Come to that, I might as well use the native Win32 API rather than TThread at all. But I'm looking for the simplest solution that works and it seems silly not to exploit the VCL.

Comment: @IanGoldby Have you found a better solution for this? I am very interested in it.

Comment: @user15124 See the accepted answer below. This is the solution I adopted.

Comment: You could have a counter in each thread on how many messages where sent from this thread and wait for 0 when thread quits. `if FreeOnTerminate and FCounter = 0 then Exit;` That would require a custom thread and messaging system though.

Comment: @user15124 I don't see how that is different from the solution I wrote up, except that with your suggestion without a synchronization object you would have to poll until FCounter became zero. Using a TCountDownEvent as described avoids this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I finally adopted.

I used a Delphi [`TCountdownEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SyncObjs.TCountdownEvent) to track the number of outstanding queued methods from my thread, incrementing the count just before queuing a method, and decrementing it as the final act of the queued method.

Just before my override of `TThread.Execute` returns, it waits for the `TCountdownEvent` object to be signalled, i.e. when the count reaches zero. This is the crucial step that guarantees that all of the queued methods have completed before `Execute` returns.

Once all of the queued methods are complete, it calls `Synchronize` with an `OnComplete` handler - thanks to Remy for pointing out that this is equivalent to but simpler than my original code that used `Queue` and `WaitForSingleObject`. (`OnComplete` is like `OnTerminate`, but called before Execute returns so that the handler can modify `FreeOnTerminate`.)

The only wrinkle is that `TCountdownEvent.AddCount` works only if the count is already greater than zero. So I wrote a class helper to implement `ForceAddCount`:

```
procedure TCountdownEventHelper.ForceAddCount(aCount: Integer);
begin
  if not TryAddCount(aCount) then
  begin
    Reset(aCount);
  end;
end;
```

Normally this would be risky, but in my case we know that by the time the thread starts waiting for number of queued methods outstanding to reach zero no more methods can be queued (so from this point once the count hits zero it will stay at zero).

This doesn't *completely* solve the problem of queued methods that handle messages, in that individual queued methods could still appear to run out of order. But I do now have the guarantee that all queued methods run asynchronously but will have completed before the thread exits. This was the primary goal, because it allows the thread to clean itself up without the risk of losing queued methods.

Answer (score 6):

`TThread.Queue()` is a FIFO queue.  In fact, it shares the same queue that `Thread.Sychronize()` uses.  But you are correct that message handling does cause queued methods to execute.  This is because `TApplication.Idle()` calls `CheckSynchronize()` whenever the message queue goes idle after processing new messages.  So if a queued/synched method invokes message processing, that can allow other queued/synched methods to being running even if the earlier method is still running.

If you want to ensure a queue method is called before the thread terminates, you should be using `Synchronize()` instead of `Queue()`, or use the `OnTerminate` event instead (which is triggered by `Synchronize()`).  What you are doing in your `finally` block is effectively the same as what the `OnTerminate` event already does natively.

Setting `FreeOnTerminate := True` in a *queued* method is asking for a memory leak.  `FreeOnTerminate` is evaluated immediately when `Execute()` exits, before `DoTerminate()` is called to trigger the `OnTerminate` event (which is an oversight in my opinion, as evaluating it that early prevents `OnTerminate` from deciding at termination time whether a thread should free itself or not after `OnTerminate` exits).  So if the queued method runs after `Execute()` has exited, there is no guarantee that `FreeOnTerminate` will be set in time.  Waiting for a *queued* method to finish before returning control to the thread is exactly what `Synchronize()` is meant for.  `Synchronize()` is synchronous, it waits for the method to exit.  `Queue()` is asynchronous, it does not wait at all.

Comment: I read your other answer suggesting calling OnTerminate via Synchronize before Execute exits. When I tried this I found that OnTerminate appeared to execute *before* the Queue()d methods so I assumed it jumped the queue. Now I know that it was because the queued methods invoked message handling and what I wrote with the WaitForSingleObject is functionally equivalent to Synchronize. But I'm still left with the original problem, which is how to get the thread to free itself, but only after all of the queued methods have completed, when the queued methods might themselves invoke message handling.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this problem by adding a call to `Synchronize()` at the end of my `Execute()` method. This forces the thread to wait till all of the calls added with `Queue()` are completed on the main thread before the call added with `Synchronize()` can be called.

```
TMyThread = class (TThread)
private
  procedure QueueMethod;
  procedure DummySync;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

procedure TMyThread.QueueMethod;
begin
  // Do something on the main thread 
  UpdateSomething;
end;

procedure TMyThread.DummySync;
begin
  // You don't need to do anything here. It's just used
  // as a fence to stop the thread ending before all the 
  // Queued messages are processed.
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while SomeCondition do 
  begin
     // Some process

     Queue(QueueMethod);
  end;
  Synchronize(DummySync);
end;
```

Comment: The simplest solution ever.

Answer (score -1):

A few thoughts:

1. FreeOnTerminate is not the end of the world if you want your thread to delete itself.
2. Semaphores let you maintain a count should you feel the need, there are such constructs.
3. There's nothing to stop you writing or using your own queueing primitives and AllocateHWnd if you want some fine grained control.