# Delphi Queue and Synchronize

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am reading Nick Hodges online and I have discovered the Queue but it is not behaving as I've expected and I couldn't understand what him and the documentation say. Look at this code:

```
 TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
   begin

     TThread.Queue(TThread.Current, procedure
                                          begin
                                           Memo1.Lines.Clear;
                                           Memo1.Lines.Add('start');
                                          end);

     Sleep(2000);

     TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current, procedure
                                          begin
                                           Memo1.Lines.Add('end');
                                          end);

   end
 ).Start;
```

I always use `Synchronize` but this time I have tried with `Queue` because according to Nick it is better in case of multiple requests since they won't be "serialized" and executed one by one. The code above works fine. Why this is not working instead?

```
 TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
   begin

     TThread.Queue(TThread.Current, procedure
                                          begin
                                           Memo1.Lines.Clear;
                                           Memo1.Lines.Add('start');
                                          end);

     Sleep(2000);

     TThread.Queue(TThread.Current, procedure
                                          begin
                                           Memo1.Lines.Add('end');
                                          end);

   end
 ).Start;
```

In this case the Memo outputs the `start` but not the end. When I call:

- Synchronize on the first and Synchronize on the second it works
- Queue on the first and Synchronize on the second it works
- Queue both times it's not working because I see only the `start` in the memo

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The difference between queue and synchronize is that [`Synchronize()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) puts the call in a queue and waits for that call to be completed and [`Queue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) puts the call in the queue and directly returns control to the thread.

However... and this is **not mentioned** in the official documentation, when a thread finishes, all the calls placed in the queue with `Queue(AThread, AMethod)`, where AThread is its **own** thread, are removed.

You can see that clearly in the source of `TThread.Destroy()` where [`RemoveQueuedEvents(Self)`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents) is called.

> RemoveQueuedEvents removes queued method calls. [...] If AThread is specified, then all method calls queued by this thread are removed.

So directly after your last `Queue()` your thread ends, `TThread.Destroy()` is executed and that last call(s) is/are removed from the queue.

There are some things you can do to solve this.

- Like mentioned in the comments you can call `TThread.Queue(nil, AMethod)`. B.T.W. Calling `TThread.Queue(AMethod)` is the same as `TThread.Queue(Self, AMethod)` so you'll always need to use the nil-variant if the thread is going to end and you want the call to finish.
- But... If you still **need the thread active** when executing the call (for some data from it), you'll need to block the thread from exiting. You can do that by using `Synchronize()` as last queue-method. Note that the last synchronize doesn't have to be a real procedure. You can just call synchronize to a dummy-procedure at the end of the `TThread.Execute` like `Synchronize(DummySync)` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40034987/1037511)). The queue is FIFO so the thread will wait until all calls in the queue are processed (including the empty dummysync).

Some extra information can be found on these pages
[Ensure all TThread.Queue methods complete before thread self-destructs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359546/ensure-all-tthread-queue-methods-complete-before-thread-self-destructs)
http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/01/30/synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters/

Comment: This can be avoided when you give `nil` as the first parameter instead of `TThread.Current`.

Comment: Why the double Queue doesn't give me the 'end' while Queue and then Sync yes?

Comment: Where are you getting this information? It's not in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue)

Comment: If this answer is true, @Raffaele, then Queue+Synchronize works because the calling thread waits for `Synchronize` to return before the thread terminates, so both functions get to run. Queue+Queue doesn't work because the second `Queue` call returns immediately, so the calling thread terminates before the main thread has time to process the second queued function. Rik says the queued function is discarded when the originating thread terminates. David and Ken doubt the veracity of the claim, though, in part because of the dubious quotation.

Comment: @KenWhite, although the resource is not first hand, I usually trust it :) 
http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/01/30/synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters/ (last paragraph). For the still non-believers: use the source.

Comment: @RobKennedy so it's better to always use Synchronize or Queue when possible and Sync at the end? Btw you should make an answer so that I can approve

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi, as I mentioned in my first comment to this answer, you can use `nil` instead of `TThread.Current` to make this work with `Queue` as well.

Comment: @UweRaabe: If the poster is going to quote something as a fact, they should provide a link to the source of the quote. I can blockquote a statement that says anything and claim it's a fact, but I'd expect someone here to challenge it until I explained who I was citing as my proof. If the poster had provided the same link as your comment as the source, I wouldn't have questioned it. :-)

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi I can confirm that passing `nil` works in this situation. I do that all the time. If you specify a thread object to `Queue()`, the request is associated with that thread. When a thread is terminated/freed, it calls `RemoveQueuedEvents()` on itself, canceling any associated queued requests that have not been processed yet. Passing `nil` to `Queue()` bypasses that so the request is not canceled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My apologizes for using the quote-method. I wasn't actually quoting an official source but wanted to convey a known statement about using Queue(). I did check the validity of the statement in the source (which I now included in my answer). I probably shouldn't have used the quotes though. I changed/expanded my answer.

Comment: @KenWhite My apologizes for using the quote-method. I wasn't actually quoting an official source but wanted to convey a known statement about using Queue(). I did check the validity of the statement in the source (which I now included in my answer). I probably shouldn't have used the quotes though. I changed/expanded my answer.

Comment: Yikes, I'm really off today. Of course I meant "My apologies ..." :)