# Delphi TThread descendant return result

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

**SITUATION**. I have created an unit with some classes to solve algebra stuff (congruences and systems), I am showing you the code:

```
type
 TCongrError = class(Exception)
 end;

type
 TCongruence = class(TComponent)
  //code stuff
  constructor Create(a, b, n: integer); virtual;
 end;

type
 TCongrSystem = array of TCongruence;

type
 TCongruenceSystem = class(TThread)
  private
   resInner: integer;
   FData: TCongrSystem;
   function modinv(u, v: integer): integer; //not relevant
  protected
   procedure Execute; override;
  public
   constructor Create(data: TCongrSystem; var result: integer; hasClass: boolean);
 end;
```

I have decided to use `TThread` because this class has an Execute method that could take some time to finish due to the length of the parameters passed to the constructor. Here's the implementation:

```
constructor TCongruenceSystem.Create(data: TCongrSystem; var result: integer; hasClass: boolean);
begin

 inherited Create(True);
 FreeOnTerminate := true;

 FData := data;
 setClass := hasClass;
 resInner := result;

end;

procedure TCongruenceSystem.Execute;
var sysResult, i, n, t: integer;
begin

 sysResult := 0;
 n := 1;

 //computation

 Queue( procedure
        begin
         ShowMessage('r = ' + sysResult.ToString);
         resInner := sysResult;
        end );

end;
```

---

**PROBLEM**

If you look at the `Queue` you see that I am using (just as test) the ShowMessage and it is showing the correct value of `sysResult`. The second line by the way has some problems that I cannot understand.

The constructor has `var result: integer` so I can have side-effect from the passed variable and then I can assign `resInner := result;`. At the end (in the Queue) I am giving `resInner` the value of sysResult and I expect `result` to be updated too due to the side effect of `var`. Why doesn't this happen?

I have made another test changing the constructor like this:

```
constructor TCongruenceSystem.Create(data: TCongrSystem; result: TMemo; hasClass: boolean);
//now of course I have resInner: TMemo
```

And changing the Queue to this:

```
Queue( procedure
        begin
         ShowMessage('r = ' + sysResult.ToString);
         resInner.Lines.Add(sysResult.ToString);
        end ); //this code now works properly in both cases! (showmessage and memo)
```

In the constructor I am passing TMemo which is a reference and ok, but isn't the original `var result: integer` passed as reference too? Why then it doesn't work?

I want to do this because I'd like to do something like this:

```
 //I put var a: integer; inside the public part of the TForm
 test := TCongruenceSystem.Create(..., a, true);
 test.OnTerminate := giveMeSolution;
 test.Start;
 test := nil;
```

Where `giveMeSolution` is just a simple procedure that uses the variable `a` containing the result of the system. If this is not possible what could I do? Basically the result at the end of Execute is just an integer number that has to be passed to the main thread.

I have read about [`ReturnValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TThread.ReturnValue) but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: This is badly designed and you should fix it sooner than later. Certainly nothing here should  be derived from TComponent. That's pointless. The bigger problem is building a thread into the component. That should be handled by the consumer of the code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for your comment. I wanted to make a component with this; reading your suggestion I think that I should remove the threading stuff and simply add a class function that does the system solve stuff.

Comment: The component is pointless. This is a numeric class. You don't need it on a design surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically the result at the end of `Execute` is just an integer number that has to be passed to the main thread.
>
> I have read about `ReturnValue` but I am not sure how to use it.

Using the `ReturnValue` property is very easy:

```
type
  TCongruenceSystem = class(TThread)
    ... 
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property ReturnValue; // protected by default
  end;

procedure TCongruenceSystem.Execute;
var
 ...
begin
  // computation
  ReturnValue := ...;
end;
```

```
test := TCongruenceSystem.Create(...);
test.OnTerminate := giveMeSolution;
test.Start;

....

procedure TMyForm.giveMeSolution(Sender: TObject);
var
  Result: Integer;
begin
  Result := TCongruenceSystem(Sender).ReturnValue;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I was looking for. Does return value accept only integers? Or also records for example?

Comment: @AlbertoMiola Only an integer.  If you want to return more complex data the best way is through a custom event like I've shown in my answer.

Comment: @AlbertoMiola: or at least through custom fields/properties of the thread class.

Comment: @J...: That has no effect on the `OnTerminate` event handler, which is fired via `Synchronize()` before the thread object is destroyed. The event handler will be able to access fields/properties of the thread object (as shown in my answer). Even your own answer takes advantage of that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, of course - sorry.  Just used to throwing away references to free-on-terminate threads.  Forgot you get one back in the `Sender`.  Totally valid.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume a class field `FFoo : integer;` ;

```
 procedure TFoo.Foo(var x : integer);
 begin
   FFoo := x;
 end;
```

Here what you are doing is assigning the *value* of `x` to `FFoo`.  Inside the method `Foo` you are free to modify the value of the variable passed in as `x` but `integers` are otherwise value types that are copied on assignment.  If you want to keep a reference to an external `integer` variable you would need to declare `FFoo` (or, in your case, `resInner`) as a `PInteger` (pointer to an integer).  For example (simplifying) :

```
TCongruenceSystem = class(TThread)
  private
    resInner: PInteger;       
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(result: PInteger);
end;
```

where

```
constructor TCongruenceSystem.Create(result: PInteger);
begin    
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := true;      
  resInner := result;    
end;
```

which you would call as `test := TCongruenceSystem.Create(@a);`  and assign:

```
 { ** See the bottom of this answer for why NOT to use }
 {    Queue with FreeOnTerminate = true **             }
 Queue( procedure
    begin
      ShowMessage('r = ' + sysResult.ToString);
      resInner^ := sysResult;
    end );
```

The reason it works with `TMemo` is that classes are reference types - their variables do not hold values but rather point to the address of the object in memory.  When you copy a class variable you are only copying a reference (ie: a pointer) whereas for value types the contents of the variable are copied on assignment.

---

With that said, there's nothing stopping you from keeping the argument typed as `var x : integer` and *taking a reference* in your constructor :

```
constructor TCongruenceSystem.Create(var result: Integer);
begin    
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := true;      
  resInner := @result;   {take the reference here}   
end;
```

but this gives the caller the impression that once the constructor is complete that you have made any modifications to the variable you intend to and they are free to dispose of the integer.  Passing explicitly as `PInteger` gives the caller a hint that your object will keep a reference to the integer they provide and that need to ensure the underlying variable remains valid while your class is alive.

And... with all that said, I still fundamentally don't like this idea.  By taking in a variable reference like this you are offloading an atypical lifetime management issue to the caller.  Passing pointers is best done in place where they are used at the point of transfer only.  Holding onto a foreign pointer is messy and it's too easy for mistakes to happen.  A far better approach here would be to provide a completion event and have the consumer of your class attach a handler.

**For example** :

```
  { define a suitable callback signature }
  TOnCalcComplete = procedure(AResult : integer) of object;

  TCongruenceSystem = class(TThread)
  private
    Fx, Fy : integer;
    FOnCalcComplete : TOnCalcComplete;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(x,y: integer);
    property OnCalcComplete : TOnCalcComplete read FOnCalcComplete write FOnCalcComplete;
  end;
```

---

```
constructor TCongruenceSystem.Create(x: Integer; y: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(true);
  FreeOnTerminate := true;
  Fx := x;
  Fy := y;
end;

procedure TCongruenceSystem.Execute;
var
  sumOfxy : integer;
begin
  sumOfxy := Fx + Fy;
  sleep(3000);        {take some time...}
  if Assigned(FOnCalcComplete) then
    Synchronize(procedure
                begin
                  FOnCalcComplete(sumOfxy);
                end);
end;
```

Which you would then call as :

```
{ implement an event handler ... }
procedure TForm1.CalcComplete(AResult: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(AResult));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LCongruenceSystem : TCongruenceSystem;
begin
  LCongruenceSystem := TCongruenceSystem.Create(5, 2);
  LCongruenceSystem.OnCalcComplete := CalcComplete;  { attach the handler }
  LCongruenceSystem.Start;
end;
```

You'll also notice that I used `Synchronize` here instead of `Queue`.  On this topic, please have a read of this question (I'll quote Remy...):

[**Ensure all TThread.Queue methods complete before thread self-destructs**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23359546/327083)

> Setting FreeOnTerminate := True in a queued method is asking for a memory leak.

Comment: Thank youvery much, I have understood my mistake I guess! I thought that with var I was able to copy the value AND the reference, not only the value but of course I was wrong.